# sending active href in view data asp.net MVC 3 @View. method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i am using asp.net MVC and have been using mvc for quite a while now but i have something along the lines of this:

```
@View.greeting | <a href="/Login/Logout">LOGOUT</a>
```

i have to but in the logout link as if i try to pass it over the @View will html encode
and show the html of the link, i would prefer to deliver a result of login or logout depending on there current status.

I know this should be simple but sometimes it is these little things that just seem to blank you out.

would appreciate a simple solution around the whole html encoding

thanks

p.s can someone create the tag for asp.net MVC 3 !!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to achieve? The code you posted works.

Comment: thanks Darin well i have to put in a link, i want View.Greeting to have the link of logout or login as it stands it always says logout even if logged in because i cant put the href into my ViewModel data without it being encoded and just showing the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this

```
@(new HtmlString(View.greeting))
```

Comment: yep thats it have never seen that  new HtmlString before thanks very much problem solved

Comment: Just incase you use MVC 2 at some point and run into the same problem you can use `@MvcHtmlString.Create(View.greeting)` as HtmlString doesn't exist